# Replace values in vector based on previous and next correct value?

Tags: r

If I have a vector like

```
x = c(1, 2, -1, -2, 5, 6, 7, -1, -2, -3, 8, 9)
```

I would like, for each negative value, to look ahead and count how many negative values there are ahead, including the current value. So the result would look like

```
y = c(0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

My ultimate goal is to use these results to create replacement values for the negative values based on the mean of the closest positive values. In this case, I want the result to be:

```
result = {1,2,(2+5)/2,(2+5)/2,5,6,7,(7+8)/2,(7+8)/2,(7+8)/2,8,9}
```

Now, I can do this using `mutate` and `lead` with different offsets but there must be a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way inspired by @Khashaa's answer:

```
approx(replace(x, x < 0, NA), xout = seq_along(x), 
  method = "constant", f = 0.5, rule = 2)$y
# [1] 1.0 2.0 3.5 3.5 5.0 6.0 7.0 7.5 7.5 7.5 8.0 9.0
```

---

*How it works in pseudocode.* Let X = replace(x, x < 0, NA).

```
X = 1  2 NA NA  5  6  7 NA NA NA  8  9
```

We are interpolating the function X(i) where i takes values in `xout` = 1..12, using data

```
  {[i, X(i)] : X(i) not NA, i = 1..12} 
= {[i, X(i)] : i = 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12}
```

Since we already have data on X(i) where it is not NA, we only need to fill intervals of NAs, that is i = 3, 4, 8, 9, 10.

- `method` = "constant" fills each interval of NAs, i = 3-4 & i = 8-10, with a single value computed based on the two nearest observations
- `f` = 0.5 weights the two observations equally
- `rule` = 2 fills missing intervals at the start or end of the vector based on the nearest observation (not applicable for this example)

For full documentation, see `?approx`.

(Thanks to @thothal for explanation and correction in comments.)

Comment: What a beautiful solution! +1  What it does it interpolates your vector to get the same length as the original vector thanks to `xout = seq_along(x)`. If `length(xout) == length(x)` it would return just `x`. However, in `approx` `NA`s are removed, which means that these removed values have to be replaced. Due to `method = constant` and `f=.5` we do it by averaging the adjacent points. One thing though, you need to add `rule=2`to deal with `x <- c(-1, 1, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

**1) na.locf0** Replace the negative values with NA and then use `na.locf0` both forwards and backwards taking the average of the two.

```
library(zoo)

x.na <- replace(x, x < 0, NA)
(na.locf0(x.na) + na.locf0(x.na, fromLast = TRUE)) / 2
## [1] 1.0 2.0 3.5 3.5 5.0 6.0 7.0 7.5 7.5 7.5 8.0 9.0
```

**2) cummax/cummin** If the non-negative numbers are non-decreasing as in the question's sample data then this would work using only base R.    We take `cummax` forward and `cummin` backward and average the two (except on the backward pass we replace negative values with `Inf`).

```
( cummax(x) +  rev(cummin(rev(replace(x, x < 0, Inf)))) ) / 2
## [1] 1.0 2.0 3.5 3.5 5.0 6.0 7.0 7.5 7.5 7.5 8.0 9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ave(x, with(rle(sign(x)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)),
    FUN = function(x) rev(seq_along(x)) * (x < 0))
# [1] 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 0
```

If you just wanted to replace the values

```
indsn = which(x < 0)
indsp = which(x > 0)
replace(x = x,
        list = x < 0,
        values = sapply(indsn, function(n){
            i = indsp[tail(which(indsp < n), 1)]
            j = indsp[head(which(indsp > n), 1)]
            mean(x[c(i, j)])
        }))
# [1] 1.0 2.0 3.5 3.5 5.0 6.0 7.0 7.5 7.5 7.5 8.0 9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To throw in a pure base solution:

```
rl <- rle(x < 0)
unlist(mapply(rl$length, rl$values, FUN = function(l, v) if (v) seq(l, 1) else rep(0, l)))
# [1] 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 3 2 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the number of consecutive negative integers, I have tried to achieve your final goal. It tries to find the series of negative numbers and replace it with the adjacent mean of the positive numbers and move ahead. I have added comments for better understanding, hope it helps. Cheers!

```
x = c(1, 2, -1, -2, 5, 6, 7, -1, -2, -3, 8, 9)
i <- 1 #iterator
while (i < length(x)){
    if (x[i]>0 & x[i+1]<0){  #check for the 1st negative number
        temp <- i+1
        while (x[temp]<0){  #check for all consectuive negative numbers  
            temp <- temp + 1
        }
        mean <- (x[temp] + x[i])/2  #find mean of the nearest positive numbers
        i <- i + 1
        while (i<temp){   #replacing all negative with the mean
            x[i] = mean
            i = i + 1
        }
    }
    i = i+1
}
print(x)
```